# EntityNotFoundException on OneToOne Mapping, even though entity exists

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "informationId")
    private Information information;
}

public class Information {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "informationId")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "information", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    private Account account;
}
```

When I make a call that retrieves an Account, I get this exception:

WARN  o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2ecc21a

WARN  o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries

WARN Unable to find Information with id 114; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Information with id 114

However, the database shows that there is an Information object with informationId 114, and an Account with a informationId foreign key of 114.

How come I am getting this exception?

**EDIT**
This is the call that causes the exception:

```
List<Following> following = followingService.findFollowingByUserId(userId);
```

In followingService, this is just a call to the dao. A `Following` object has a `User` object, and the `User` owns an `Account`. The following object populates just fine if I remove the Account mapping

Comment: Could you give us the rest of the classes, especially the Id definition in Information class ?

Comment: @ThomasMartin I refactored my post to include more information

Answer (score 0):

Can you post complete code where this entity is being persisted and fetched?
This information is not sufficient to answer this query.

Comment: please see revised post above

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you have a table with 1 entity and the other table with 0?
For me it seems like this:

```
Account
ID | Name | InformationID
-------------------------
1  | Acc  | 114
-------------------------

Information
ID | Name | Account
-------------------
-------------------
```